# can i specific autolayout constraints for 4.7 and 5.5

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, autolayout

can i specific and different constraints by just using autolayout and storyboard for 4.7 (iPhone 6) and (iPhone 6 plus)

e.g i want the icon have 50pixel for 4", 60 pixel for 4.7" and 66 for 5.5" iphone .?

Comment: You can do this using auto layout just adding proper constraints

Answer (score 1):

Hi yes you have two ways:

- Relate the width of the icon to the width of the screen. Indeed, if you want the width of the icon to be `50px` when the screen is 4'' so `320px`, the multiplier is `50.0/320.0 = 0.15625`:

  ```
  NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint  
                                      constraintWithItem:iconImageView 
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                      toItem:self.view 
                                      attribute:attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                                      multiplier:0.15625 
                                      constant:0]; 

  [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
  ```

  obviously set also the constraint `proportional width/height` on the `iconImageView`. 
  By this proportion the icon width (and so height) on iPhone 6+ will result `414*0.15625 = 64.6875`;
- the second way it is just to have an `IBOutlet` to the fixed width constraint of the `iconImageView` and change it from the code checking the width of the screen:

  ```
  if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width == 320.0) {
      myConstraintsWidth.constant = 50.0;
  } .... and so on
  ```

  Also here obviously set also the constraint `proportional width/height` on the `iconImageView`.

IMO I hugely prefer the first option. It is clean and works really well.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you were asking whether it is possible to set the constraints using Storyboard only, I'm afraid the answer is negative, which means you must implement some code.

Example: Please note this is hard-coding and not elegant, just showing you the spirit

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH MIN([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)

- (void)setImageWidthConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint *)imageWidthConstraint {
    if (SCREEN_WIDTH == 320) { //iPhone 5s or earlier
        imageWidthConstraint.constant = 50;
    } else if (SCREEN_WIDTH == 375) { //iPhone 6
        imageWidthConstraint.constant = 60;
    } else if (SCREEN_WIDTH == 414) { //iPhone 6 Plus
        imageWidthConstraint.constant = 66;
    }
}
```